# Azure "peek" the whole queue?

Tags: azure, azure-queues

I have a queue of messages that I would like to read. Consider the following code, based on a queue of 100 items:

```
queue.FetchAttributes();
            var orderCount = queue.ApproximateMessageCount;
            while(orderCount > 0)
            {
                var messages = queue.GetMessages(32,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                if (messages != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in messages)
                    {
                        Order singleOrder = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Order>(item.AsString);
                        PendingOrders.Add(singleOrder);
                    }
                }
                queue.FetchAttributes();
                orderCount = (messages == null) ? 0 : queue.ApproximateMessageCount;
            }
```

In this instance, 3 calls will be made to "queue.GetMessages()" to retrieve 96 messages, followed by a 4th call to get the remaining 4. The loop will then exit and the list of items returned. 
When I run this, it appears to be lifting the same items over and over i.e. not incrementing. I was under the impression when I read an item, it removed it from the queue temporarily? So each time I read a message, it gets temporarily removed from my queue - in this case for 1 minute. Have I missed a step? 
Note, I am not calling 'DeQueue' anywhere as I want the item to return to the queue after 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `queue.GetMessages`, you're actually performing a `Dequeue` operation on your queue. [`GetMessages`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.getmessages.aspx) operation actually makes the messages fetched invisible for a duration of 1 minute.

However the messages are not removed from the queue. So when you call [`queue.FetchAttributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.fetchattributes.aspx) which populates [`ApproximateMessageCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.approximatemessagecount.aspx) property of the queue will always return the same number (100). Thus depending on how much time you spend in executing `PendingOrders.Add(singleOrder);` line of code, it is entirely possible that you get the same messages back. If it takes more than a minute to loop over 32 messages, then these messages become visible again (enqueued in other words) and in the next iteration you get the same messages back.